# Не работает хук МойСклад на входящий платеж

Tags: php, moysklad-json-api, мойсклад-api

Есть такой хук

```
[id] => e3614a1d-72ac-11e9-9109-f8fc000becc9
[entityType] => paymentin
[url] => https://domen.ru/script.php
[method] => POST
[enabled] => 1
[action] => DELETE
```

в script.php следующий код

```
<?php
$hand=fopen("hook.log","a+");
fwrite($hand,date("H:i:s",time())."TEST - \n");
fclose($hand);
```

Ожидаю, что при ручном удалении входящего платежа, в hook.log появится запись, однако подцепленный скрипт вообще не срабатывает.

Может кто сталкивался с этой проблемой?

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, хуки на событие DELETE срабатывают при полном удалении сущности. В моем же случае платеж просто переносится в корзину, что является обновлением.
Проверил с хуком на UPDATE, работает.

Comment: Да, все верно. Корзина это временное хранилище документов, но не само удаление.